# Error Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, crud

I'm using a callback after inserting in the database, to pass values to this other table, i think the method i used its fine. But it gives me this error when its inserting to the other table in the database, probably in my model, or something in the controller im kind of clueless in this error, can someone please help me. 
Before someone say its to put $this->load->database(); its already in my autoload in config file :)

***Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object***

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Finances::$inventory_model
>
> Filename: controllers/finances.php
>
> Line Number: 125

**CONTROLLER:**

```
public function inventory_management($post_array,$primary_key)
    {  
        $this->load->model('inventory_model');

        if($post_array['id_expense']!=null){
            $type = 'add';
            $id_exp_detail = $primary_key;

            $result = $this->inventory_model->insert([
                'id_exp_detail' => $id_exp_detail,
                'name' => $post_array['brand'],
                'quantity' => $post_array['item_quantity'],
                'lote' => $post_array['package_code'];
                'type' => $type,
                'date' => date(),
                'id_user' => $this->session->userdata('id_user'),
                'id_entity' => $this->session->userdata('id_entity')
            ]);
        }else if ($post_array['name']!=null){
            $type = 'sub';
            $id_treatment = $primary_key;

            $result = $this->inventory_model->insert([
                'id_treatment' => $id_treatment,
                'name' => $post_array['name'],
                'quantity' => $post_data['recomended_dose'],
                'lote' => $post_array['id_package'],
                'type' => $type,
                'date' => date(),
                'id_user' => $this->session->userdata('id_user'),
                'id_entity' => $this->session->userdata('id_entity')
            ]);
        }else{
            $type = 'sub';
            $id_fertilization = $primary_key;

            $result = $this->inventory_model->insert([
                'id_fertilization' => $id_fertilization,
                'name' => $post_data['name'],
                'quantity' => $post_data['quantity'],
                'lote' => $post_data['id_package'],
                'type' => $type,
                'date' => date(),
                'id_user' => $this->session->userdata('id_user'),
                'id_entity' => $this->session->userdata('id_entity')
            ]);
        }

        if($result){
            echo "validation Complete";
        }

    }
```

**MODEL**

```
class CRUD_model extends CI_Model
{

    protected $_table = null;
    protected $_primary_key = null;

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }


    public function insert($data)
    {

        $this->db->insert($this->_table, $data);
        // return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
```

**MODEL:**

```
class inventory_model extends CRUD_model
{
    protected $_table = 'inventory_management';
    protected $_primary_key = 'id';

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the wrong you call wrong model file

```
$this->load->model('inventory_model');
```

it should be

```
$this->load->model('crud_model');
```

and you use wrong way to pass array in function

```
$param = array('id_exp_detail' => $id_exp_detail, 'name' => $post_array['brand'], 'quantity' => $post_array['item_quantity'], 'lote' => $post_array['package_code'], 'type' => $type, 'date' => date(), 'id_user' => $this->session->userdata('id_user'), 'id_entity' => $this->session->userdata('id_entity')); 

$result = $this->inventory_model->insert($param);
```

Comment: I should have posted the inventory model, so everyone could understand, my bad.

Comment: this is the line 125$result = $this->inventory_model->insert([

Comment: @RicardoOrigin you use wrong way to pass array into model . I edited my code please check

Comment: Do you get the same error if you use `CRUD_model` instead of `inventory_model`? I understand that in `CRUD_model` table and primary key are not defined and it leads to a db error.

Comment: I will check as soon when i enter in my desktop again. Thx for the time and help

Comment: Then problem in your query and database. Try to create arrar as per your database field and try

Comment: I think you write wrong insert function in your model use table name instead of this->insert

Comment: problem resolved i put the load->model in the function construct and now all is fine thx